# How to assign the same value to the end_date field as is selected in the star_date field

Tags: php, html, date, variables

I would like the user to be able to select the start_date and automatically (without the user selecting anything) have the same value appear in the end date. Here is the code snippet I have extracted:

```
                <?php
                $required         = 'false';
                $start_date_value = '';

                if ( 'yes' == $settings['cwbf_start_date_required'] ) {
                    $required = 'true';
                }

                if ( isset( $_GET['start_date'] ) ) {
                    $start_date_value = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['start_date'] ) );
                }
                $start_place_holder = __( 'Día de la reserva', 'codup-filters-for-woo-booking' );
                ?>
                <input name="start_date" id="start_date" validate-required="<?php echo wp_kses_post( $required ); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo wp_kses_post( $start_place_holder ); ?>" autocomplete="off" min="<?php echo wp_kses_post( gmdate( 'Y-m-d' ) ); ?>" type="text"  value="<?php echo wp_kses_post( $start_date_value ); ?>" />
            </div>
            <?php
            if ( 'yes' == $settings['cwbf_end_date_enable'] ) {
                ?>
                <div class="filter-row">
                    <label class="cwbf-fields-label">
                <?php
                if ( '' != $settings['cwbf_end_date_text'] ) {
                    echo wp_kses_post( $settings['cwbf_end_date_text'] );
                } else {
                    esc_attr_e( 'End Date', 'codup-filters-for-woo-booking' );
                }
                ?>
                    </label>

                <?php
                $required       = 'false';
                $end_date_value = '';

                if ( 'yes' == $settings['cwbf_end_date_required'] ) {
                    $required = 'true';
                }

                if ( isset( $_GET['end_date'] ) ) {
                    $end_date_value = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['end_date'] ) );
                }
                $end_place_holder = __( 'Place your End Date here', 'codup-filters-for-woo-booking' );
                ?>
                <input name="end_date" id="end_date" validate-required="<?php echo wp_kses_post( $required ); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo wp_kses_post( $end_place_holder ); ?>" autocomplete="off" min="<?php echo wp_kses_post( gmdate( 'Y-m-d' ) ); ?>" type="text"  value="<?php echo wp_kses_post( $end_date_value ); ?>" />
                </div>
                <?php
```

I am a newbie in html and php but I think this is a critical issue for my project, thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you want the end date to only be set if it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery:

```
$('#start_date').on('change', function(){
    $('#end_date').val($(this).val())
})
```

I did not test it in a real environment but I guess it should work without any bugs.

Edit: as @Martin mentioned:

1. Add jquery to your page. You can use this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) to add it.
2. The above code is just a UI trigger that updates the `end_date` value after the `start_date` input is changed by the user. So it's all in the frontend.

Comment: I suspect the OP wants the end date to only be set if that value is currently empty or unset. Also, could you edit your post and add some explanation to the OP what the JQuery actually does? Thanks. You may also need to highlight that they will need to import JQuery before using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```js
const startDate = document.querySelector('#start_date');
const endDate = document.querySelector('#end_date');

startDate.addEventListener('change', function() {
  endDate.value = startDate.value;
});
```